# PyQt5 looping issue, only last iteration of QWebEngineView object works

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have no prior experience with Qt/PyQt.
I'm just trying to use PyQt for the web engine capabilities, to 'convert' a folder of html files to pdf documents.

The code works well if there is only 1 html file, but when there are multiple html files **it only generates a pdf for the last file in the loop**.

I think the issue must be to do with Qt stuff, looping, events etc - but I have no idea where to begin to sort this out. As you can tell I'm only Qt to produce html->pdf, I'm not interested in building a GUI.

I read about using `QApplication.processEvents()` at the end of the loop may fix this, but the result was the same.
I tried adding a sleep/pause to the code, also the same.

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, QUrl

# read somewhere this is needed to load local html, works without for me though
sys.argv.append("--disable-web-security")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

iter_num = 0

directory = 'my_webfile_directory'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".htm") or filename.endswith(".html"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r') as myfile:

            print(filename)
            raw_html = myfile.read()
            # init qt web view
            view = QWebEngineView()
            view.setHtml(raw_html)

            # set to close web view after pdf is created
            view.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(view.close)
            # generate filename
            iter_num += 1
            outputfilename = str(iter_num) + ".pdf"
            outputfullpath = os.path.join(directory, outputfilename)

            def save_pdf(finished):
                view.page().printToPdf(outputfullpath)
            # when web view is ready, save the pdf
            view.loadFinished.connect(save_pdf)
            # QApplication.processEvents()

app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `QWebEngineView` is not thread-safe because I was able to make it work consistently by creating a queue of files to be processed and executing one after the other using a signal, here is a demo application:

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QDir, QUrl, pyqtSignal


class HtmlToPdfConverter(QObject):

    queueProcessed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._queue = []
        self._current = None

    def queue(self, html_file, output_file):
        self._queue.append((html_file, output_file))

    def process_queue(self):
        if self._queue:
            raw_html = ''
            self._current = self._queue.pop(0)
            with open(self._current[0], 'r') as my_file:
                raw_html = my_file.read()

            view = QWebEngineView()
            view.loadFinished.connect(self._get_load_finished_event(view))
            view.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(self._get_printing_finished_event(view))
            view.setHtml(raw_html)
        else:
            self.queueProcessed.emit()

    def _get_load_finished_event(self, view):
        def _load_finished(success):
            if success:
                view.page().printToPdf(self._current[1])
        return _load_finished

    def _get_printing_finished_event(self, view):
        def _printing_finished(file, success):
            view.close()
            self.process_queue()
        return _printing_finished


class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super().__init__(sys_argv)

        self.dummy_window = QMainWindow()
        self.dummy_window.show()

    def generate_pdfs(self, directory):
        converter = HtmlToPdfConverter()
        converter.queueProcessed.connect(self._queue_processed)

        iter_num = 0

        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            if filename.endswith(".htm") or filename.endswith(".html"):
                iter_num += 1
                out_filename = os.path.join(directory, str(iter_num) + ".pdf")
                converter.queue(os.path.join(directory, filename), out_filename)

        converter.process_queue()

    def _queue_processed(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self.dummy_window, 'Pdf Generator', 'All PDF files have been generated.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(sys.argv)
    app.generate_pdfs('c:/temp/test')

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but using your code, at least for me - in a folder of 3 html files, only the 2nd PDF gets generated.

- edit. It's not consistent. Sometimes I get only 1 pdf file, sometimes 2, sometimes all 3.
All 3 html files are identical in my testing.

Comment: Just simple HTML - https://pastebin.com/FTqiTmQJ
win32.
When using 3 identical html files, usually only 1 or 2 pdfs are generated. But no errors in command line.

But when using 7 of these html files, and running using command prompt (not within VS Code) now I get more information about about the errors:

[764:6240:1114/095012.944:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
[764:6240:1114/095012.947:ERROR:print_web_view_helper.cc(1579)] 


I get a many of these errors printed after the final html file names is printed.

Very strange
Thanks

Comment: I was able to reproduce it, I will try to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can confirm this happens on win64 pyqt 5.11, and win32 pyqt 5.10.

Comment: Check the updated answer... Hopefully it will work now.

Comment: Wow this is much more complex! But it works correctly (although there is a GUI popup, I can live with it!).
Thank you for helping with this, I appreciate it.